# NO compatible agent error for for teamcity plugin

Tags: teamcity

I have created a simple HelloWorld plugin for teamcity. However when i try to run it i get below error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9F3P.png)

there is no specific dependancy. also when i remove my plugin from build step the agent automatically becomes compatible. Any help on this would be helpfull

Regards
Nik

Comment: Which plugin..?

Comment: Can you let me know the buildagent.properties file for the agent? My purpose of asking is that if you are missing any Environment variables for the agent. Agents do not take the system env variabled but maitains its own env variables in "D:\BuildAgent1\conf\buildagent.properties" file, where D drive is where I installed my agent.

Comment: Hi Rishab sure i am sharing it here https://github.com/nbhoski/teamcity/blob/main/Buildagent.properties

Comment: Hi @KumarRishabh does this properties file makes any sense

Comment: Nothing wrong here. I am assuming the plugin is installed correctly and you can see that plugin in  Administration | Plugins List just to verify the plugin was installed correctly. Also it should also specify somewhere that what are the  'Unmet requirements' for the agents. And may be look for other compatible agents if you have any.